# Alternative to USER_ERRORS to find compilation errors

Tags: oracle

If I want to get the errors of a procedure I can find it in the USER_ERRORS table. I am searching for an alternative way for my Java application. I need a query, or a different method, so that I can catch compilation errors of a procedure.

For example the following procedure will compile with an error:

```
    create or replace procedure testprc is
    sql_txt varchar2(11);
    begin
    select count(1) into sql_txt FROM ctsmessages
    end;
```

I can go run `select * from user_errors` to find out that the error was due to a missing semi-colon. Is there another alternative?

Comment: Why are you creating procedures from your application? Or do you really want to catch run-time exceptions when you call an existing procedure, rather than compile-time errors when you create a new one?

Comment: @AlexPoole I am running the procedure from the application, If an error popped up , I want to know it.

Comment: A run-time error will be reported as an `SQLException` by JDBC, and won't be in `user_errors`. If the procedure you call is invalid then you'll get a 'failed revalidation' run-time exception and could then query `user_errors`, but that wouldn't be something I'd expect to see often, if ever, in live code so handling it seems like overkill to me.

Comment: you said ' If the query is invalid I have to query user_errors'. I cannot get it in another way right ? @AlexPoole

Comment: If the procedure itself has a compilation error and fails revalidation when called then you'd have to look at `user_errors`; but if that happened I'd report it and get that looked at externally. If the procedure is valid and raises an exception at run-time - bad data, no data found, it does a `raise_application_error` etc. - then that will *not* be in `user_errors`, but will reported as an SQLException.

Comment: @AlexPoole if the procedure has a compilation error , can I find the error from another place then user_errors ?

Comment: No. Well, [`all_errors` or `dba_errors`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_1085.htm), but they're aspects of the same thing. Why don't you want to query `user_errors`; what's driving you to look for an alternative?

Comment: we used to work on powerbuilder. when the procedure compiled an error , the powerbuilder wil take the error number (exapmle like ora-0091 ) and compare it in his library. the library contain all the error numbers for ora and sybase. I am searching for an alterantive because there are somecase the user errors wont show us the correct error. @AlexPoole